# How to get Album ID from Song URI

Tags: java, android

Using the Official Java/Kotlin Android SDK distributed by Google, I'm looking to get the album art of a song by querying the mediastore for the song and finding the album ID of the album it belongs to (with which I should be able to fetch the album art). However, all the seemingly relevant questions I've found describe how one might design a method that takes the Album ID as input and returns the album art as output, however, I am trying to find out how to *get the Album ID*.

I have users select a song using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, and get its URI in return. How can I use this URI to find the id of the album the song at the URI belongs to?

Comment: Please explain what toolkit/language/framework are you working on. These should be also added as tags. Try to come up with an example of the expected code.

Comment: I thought I tagged this as an Android issue? I'll try to elaborate a bit more if it helps.

Comment: You mean all the android frameworks? https://medium.com/@MasterOfCodeGlobal/best-10-android-frameworks-for-building-android-apps-44ceb3756880 https://yalantis.com/blog/list-of-best-frameworks-for-android-app-development/ Yp, please try :)

Comment: @Rbjz fixed :) thanks for pointing that out